# does the file extension matter to DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

I have a SQL script file with the extension.pgsql

When I open it in DBeaver, it does not seem to recognise it as a SQL script and removes all options such as execute, etc...

If I change the extension from pgsql into sql, then everything is fine.

I do not have control over file extensions... 
Is there a way to instruct DBeaver to treat .pgsql as SQL files?

PS: I am using DBeaver 5.3.4 under windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the extension does matter and yes you can add file associations to treat .pgsql extensions as SQL files.

Go to File > Properties (Alt+Enter is default keybind). Then Click on Global Settings.
Navigate to General > Editors > File Associations.
Click Add and add .pgsql
[image]

[image]

Then add an associated editor that is an sql editor.
[image]